# Houndmouth's influences

Tags: influence

I have been really enjoying Houndmouth's two albums lately and I was wondering if anyone knew what their influences are?  They have an interesting twang that I have not heard from any bands I listen to and I really like it.  Almost like a darker country music, are there other bands like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this [interview](http://www.thewaster.com/interview/houndmouth-kind-of-life/) of the drummer Shane Cody by [The Waster](http://www.thewaster.com):

> “We all went on a big **Neil Young** kick a few years ago.

They are said to be influenced by [The Band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Band), as speculated by some media [here](http://www.musicomh.com/reviews/albums/houndmouth-from-the-hills-below-the-city), [here](https://www.theguardian.com/music/2012/jul/06/new-band-houndmouth) and [here](http://www.musicomh.com/reviews/albums/houndmouth-little-neon-limelight), even Houndsmouth denied it :

From [The Waster](http://www.thewaster.com/interview/houndmouth-kind-of-life/):

> "**The Band** (...) we had never really listened to them, everybody knew, *The Weight*, and *Up On Cripple Creek*,  but we had never delved into the deep cuts.”

From [Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/michael-bialas/meet-houndmouth-the-best_b_7262374.html), the guitarist Matt Myers said:

> We really didn’t listen to **The Band** all that much before the comparison. And then we went back and kind of discovered everything and then got into **Neil Young**, **John Prine**.”